# Attribute of xml namespace

Tags: c#, .net

I am need to get attribute from node.

Sometimes I get different attribute, e.g sometimes it is `<attribute id="0x1162834">` and sometimes `<attribute-list id="0x1162834">`, and I don't know how to get the attribute

Thanks for any help.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<model-response-list
    xmlns="http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response" total-models="6119" throttle="1000">
    <model-responses>
        <model mh="0x504067">
            <attribute id="0x12d7f">XX.XXX.XX.X</attribute>
            <attribute id="0x11ee8">2</attribute>
            <attribute id="0x118b9"></attribute>
            <attribute error="NoSuchAttribute" id="0x1162834"/>
            <attribute error="NoSuchAttribute" id="0x1161461"/>
        </model>
        <model mh="0x40007f">
            <attribute id="0x12d7f">XX.XX.XX.X</attribute>
            <attribute id="0x11ee8">9</attribute>
            <attribute-list id="0x1162834">
                <instance oid="0" value=" Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz       "/>
                <instance oid="1" value=" Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz       "/>
            </attribute-list>
            <attribute-list id="0x1161461">
                <instance oid="0" value="6"/>
                <instance oid="1" value="6"/>
            </attribute-list>
        </model>
    </model-responses>
    <link type="application/xml" href="http://spectrum/spectrum/restful/devices/?id=53c271cb-cb69-4b13-b95f-50e39ebecd5e&amp;start=1000&amp;throttlesize=1000" rel="next"/>
</model-response-list>
```

This is my code in C#:

```
using (System.IO.Stream s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{
    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
    {
        var XMLResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(XMLResponse);

        XName qualifiedName = XName.Get("model", "http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response");

        foreach (var device_handel in xmlDoc.Descendants(qualifiedName))
        {
            XName QN_attr = XName.Get("attribute", "http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response");

            attr_devices[0] = device_handel.Descendants(QN_attr).Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "0x12d7f").Select(e => e).Single().Value;
            attr_devices[1] = device_handel.Descendants(QN_attr).Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "0x11ee8").Select(e => e).Single().Value;
            attr_devices[2] = device_handel.Descendants(QN_attr).Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "0x118b9").Select(e => e).Single().Value;
            attr_devices[3] = device_handel.Descendants(QN_attr).Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "0x1162834").Select(e => e).Single().Value;
            attr_devices[4] = device_handel.Descendants(QN_attr).Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "0x1161461").Select(e => e).Single().Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could begin with something like this:

```
XName qualifiedName = XName.Get("model", "http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response");
XName QN_attr = XName.Get("attribute", "http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response");
XName QN_attrList = XName.Get("attribute-list", "http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response");

foreach (var device_handel in xmlDoc.Descendants(qualifiedName))
{
    var attrsAndLists = device_handel.Elements().Where(x => x.Name == QN_attr || x.Name == QN_attrList).ToArray();

    attr_devices[0] = attrsAndLists.Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "0x12d7f").Select(e => e.Value).SingleOrDefault();
    attr_devices[1] = attrsAndLists.Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "0x11ee8").Select(e => e.Value).SingleOrDefault();
    attr_devices[2] = attrsAndLists.Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "0x118b9").Select(e => e.Value).SingleOrDefault();
    attr_devices[3] = attrsAndLists.Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "0x1162834").Select(e => e.Value).SingleOrDefault();
    attr_devices[4] = attrsAndLists.Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "0x1161461").Select(e => e.Value).SingleOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", attr_devices));
}
```

Note that `attribute-list` has a different structure from `attribute`. While the second has a text element containing the "value", it isn't clear what you want to extract from the first. Ah and in your xml, the `id="0x118b9"` is present only in the first model, and not in the second model.

To extract the `value` of `attribute-list` do something like:

```
XName QN_instance = XName.Get("instance", "http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response");
```

...

```
attr_devices[0] = attrsAndLists.Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("id") == "0x12d7f").Select(e => e.Name == QN_attr ? e.Value : e.Elements(QN_instance).Select(f => (string)f.Attribute("value")).FirstOrDefault()).SingleOrDefault();
```

(note that I've removed all the various `.Value` and replaced them with `(string)` cast. It is a little better, because in case of missing attribute it won't throw an exception.

And you should make a method and put the entire `attrsAndLists.Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("id") == "0x12d7f").Select(e => e.Name == QN_attr ? e.Value : e.Elements(QN_instance).Select(f => (string)f.Attribute("value")).FirstOrDefault()).SingleOrDefault()` inside, instead of repeating it five times.

Comment: how to get the attribute("value") of the first node from the list?